# Import data from CSV file to datagrid

Tags: vb.net, csv, uwp, datagrid

I have an app UWP where I import data from CSV file to a ListView.

How can I put data to a DataGrid? Now I use this code from put the data into a ListView:

```
Dim CsvRows = New ObservableCollection(Of String)()

Dim picker = New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker()
picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv")

Dim file = Await picker.PickSingleFileAsync()

CsvRows.Clear()

Using csvReader = New CsvParse.CsvFileReader(Await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        Dim row = New CsvParse.CsvRow()

        While csvReader.ReadRow(row)
            Dim newRow = ""

            For i = 0 To row.Count
                newRow += row(i) + ","

                i += 1
            Next

            CsvRows.Add(newRow)
        End While

End Using

GridTabacchi.ItemsSource = CsvRows
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a .CSV upload in my company's VB .NET application to be displayed in a grid.  This is how I did it:

```
Dim dt as DataTable = New DataTable
Dim firstLine As Boolean = True

 Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(txtFileLocation.Text.Trim())
     Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
         If firstLine Then
            firstLine = False
            Dim cols() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
            For Each col As String In cols
                dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(col, GetType(String)))
             Next
          Else
             Dim data() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
             dt.Rows.Add(data)
          End If
      Loop
 sr.Close()

 dataGrid.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When i load a CSV file from desktop, return an error "Access to the path is denied. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Make sure you do not have the file open in Excel or  a document.  Also right click on the file, check the Properties and insure that it is not Read Only.

Comment: The file is not Read Only and is closed :/

Comment: You might check the security setting for the document.  Insure that you have Read/Write privileges.  Check out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-f  Or https://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-file-access-denied-68193.html

Comment: And if I install my app on another pc, does the app works?

Comment: We have our app installed on multiple computers and never had any issue with uploading the files.  Perhaps you should move it from your desktop into your documents folder and try it again.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Import data from CSV file to datagrid

In general, we often use [`CsvReader`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/12.2.1) covert the csv file to collection that could bind to `DataGrid` column directly. And this is official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics)  that you could refer. I will provide sample code below.

**Model Class**

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Link As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Remark As String
    Public Property Time As String
End Class
```

**Code behind**

```
Private Sub DataGrid_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Using reader = New StreamReader("Assets\Archive.csv", True)

        Using csv = New CsvReader(reader)
            Dim records = csv.GetRecords(Of Item)()

            For Each item In records
                Items.Add(item)
            Next
        End Using
    End Using

    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Items
End Sub
```

Make  `DataGridTextColumn` base on your model class and bind each property like below.

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Id}"
        Header="ID"
        Tag="Id"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Title}"
        Header="Title"
        Tag="Title"
        />
    <controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Link}"
        Header="Link"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind source}"
        Tag="Link"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Type}"
        Header="Type"
        Tag="Type"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Remark}"
        Header="Remark"
        Tag="Remark"
        />
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn
        Width="*"
        Binding="{Binding Time}"
        Header="Time"
        Tag="Time"
        />
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```